# highlight flow step or activity step in the rehosted workflow designer by entering display name

Tags: workflow, designer

I need to search for workflow step for example by name, then I need to select it by code and the activity should be highlighted like if I clicked on it using mouse.

I tried to the above approach
but when I use the following code to select the flowstep
workflowDesigner.Context.Items.SetValue(new Selection(new[] { flowstep}));

I didn't see the activity as highlighted or any indication that this activity is selected

we need to develop search feature for the rehosted workflow designer any ideas!

Comment: Did you get anywhere with that? I'm looking for the same.